# Unable to load asset: lib/assets/background.jpg

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is it i cant load background image in my project? ***Unable to load asset: lib/assets/background.jpg***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget testWidget = new MediaQuery(
    data: new MediaQueryData(), child: new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("lib/assets/background.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: null /* add child content here */,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

file tree

[image]

pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - lib/assets/background.jpg
```

Comment: Try wrapping MyApp into material app while calling main's runApp method.
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

Comment: the error says `Unable to load asset: lib/assets/background.jpg`

Comment: Then update your question i didn't find anything like this in question or description: Unable to load asset: lib/assets/background.jpg

Comment: Move assets folder out side of lib

and set

assets:
  - assets/images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make3 folder under `lib` folder. Your structure for assets folder as per below.

[image]

And `pubspecs.yaml`

[image]

Comment: is there a specific reason to not to add assets inside lib folder?

Comment: Flutter has to give default flow and structure to define assets. And it's outside of the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to remove this code:

```
Widget testWidget = new MediaQuery(
data: new MediaQueryData(), child: new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
```

Move assets folder to the root of the project and update the path in pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - /assets/
```

Change `MyApp` to use MaterialApp and `HomePage`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then move the background image code to the `HomePage` inside the `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/background.jpg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**if your assets included into androin folder...try this**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    -android/assests/directory/
```